# How would I be able to track change based on time? Identify when the condition first appeared - R

Tags: r, tidyverse

If I have a data set with different cases over time, what would be the best way to track change?

Let's say I tracked if there color change in walls over time; think weather damage. I was never consistent in the day or time I started tracking or tracked it. I have duplicate rows in terms of walls because each row represents the measurement at a specific time.

What would be the best way for me to identify which walls' changed at some point?

```
Wall   Color   Date
A      yellow  2019-08
A      white  2019-02
A      yellow    2019-05
A      yellow  2019-05   
A      white  2019-04
A      white  2019-03
A      yellow  2019-08   
B      yellow  2019-09
B      white  2019-05
B      yellow  2020-09
B      yellow  2020-05
c      white  2019-05
c      white  2018-01
c      white  2020-06
c      white  2019-02
c      white  2020-03
c      yellow  2020-09
c      white  2020-06
c      yellow  2020-05
c      white  2019-01
c      yellow  2020-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::separate(Date, c('Year', 'Month'), convert = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(Wall, Year, Month) %>%
  group_by(Wall) %>%
  mutate(change = Color != lag(Color, default = first(Color)), 
         change = row_number() == which(change)[1])

#   Wall  Color   Year Month change
#   <chr> <chr>  <int> <int> <lgl> 
# 1 A     white   2019     2 FALSE 
# 2 A     white   2019     3 FALSE 
# 3 A     white   2019     4 FALSE 
# 4 A     yellow  2019     5 TRUE  
# 5 A     yellow  2019     5 FALSE 
# 6 A     yellow  2019     8 FALSE 
# 7 A     yellow  2019     8 FALSE 
# 8 B     white   2019     5 FALSE 
# 9 B     yellow  2019     9 TRUE  
#10 B     yellow  2020     5 FALSE 
# … with 11 more rows
```

Comment: This is partially it! I think that I would just want one TRUE per "Wall", so just identify the date when it changed. So if it changed in 2020-03 to yellow then only 2020-03 would be marked for "Wall" A.

Comment: Ok..see updated answer to get only first `TRUE`  for each `Wall`. Also I guess `Date` should also be considered here. Updated answer should help.

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, what was the reason for splitting up the month and year?

Comment: Because `2019-08` is a character value and R doesn't understand it as date. So there are two options that we can take 1) Split into month and year or 2) Convert into date. We could chose any of the option but I chose 1.

Comment: Oh, okay. Is there a way to modify this to track increase / decrease? I know for this example the changers at categorical, but in the case of continuous ones. Or would that require a completely different code?

Comment: It is better if you ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Thank you! I did and got some great answers. For anyone who is interested:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65344638/identifying-type-of-change-in-continuous-values-r/65345458#65345458

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out what is desired but his is a bit of R code taht shows how to do some of the operations that I think you do not yet have a handle on:

```
> dat <- scan( text="A      yellow  2019-08
+ A      white  2019-02
+ A      yellow    2019-05
+ A      yellow  2019-05   
+ A      white  2019-04
+ A      white  2019-03
+ A      yellow  2019-08   
+ B      yellow  2019-09
+ B      white  2019-05
+ B      yellow  2020-09
+ B      yellow  2020-05
+ c      white  2019-05
+ c      white  2018-01
+ c      white  2020-06
+ c      white  2019-02
+ c      white  2020-03
+ c      yellow  2020-09
+ c      white  2020-06
+ c      yellow  2020-05
+ c      white  2019-01
+ c      yellow  2020-1", what=list(grp="",color="",mon=""))
Read 21 records
> dat=data.frame(dat)
> dat
   grp  color     mon
1    A yellow 2019-08
2    A  white 2019-02
3    A yellow 2019-05
4    A yellow 2019-05
5    A  white 2019-04
6    A  white 2019-03
7    A yellow 2019-08
8    B yellow 2019-09
9    B  white 2019-05
10   B yellow 2020-09
11   B yellow 2020-05
12   c  white 2019-05
13   c  white 2018-01
14   c  white 2020-06
15   c  white 2019-02
16   c  white 2020-03
17   c yellow 2020-09
18   c  white 2020-06
19   c yellow 2020-05
20   c  white 2019-01
21   c yellow  2020-1
> library(zoo)
> dat$mon<-as.yearmon(dat$mon)
> plot(as.numeric(dat$color)~dat$mon)
> plot(as.numeric(dat$color)~dat$mon, type="b")
> png(); 
  plot(jitter(as.numeric(dat$color)) ~dat$mon, type="b", col=as.numeric(dat$grp));
  dev.off()
```

[image]

I think it shows that you have not yet described the problem in sufficient detail to allow a coherent response.